# Java, need a while loop to reach eof. i.e.while !eof, keep parsing

Tags: java, while-loop, eof, datainputstream

I currently have a working parser. It parses a file once(not what I want it to do) and then outputs parsed data into a file. I need it to keep parsing and appending to the same output file until the end of the input file.  Looks something like this.

```
try {
// my code parsing the data and appending to eof of output. (works)
}
catch (EOFException eof){
}
```

Everything is done except the while loop.  It only parses once when I need it to keep parsing.  I'm looking for a while loop function to reach eof.

I'm also using a DataInputStream. Is there some sort of DataInputStream.hasNext function?

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));
i.e. dis.read();
```

.

```
//Need a while !eof while loop
try {
// my code parsing the data and appending to eof of output. (works)
}
catch (EOFException eof){
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Warning**: This answer is incorrect. See the comments for explanation.

---

Instead of looping until an EOFException is thrown, you could take a much cleaner approach, and use [`available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29).

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));
while (dis.available() > 0) {
    // read and use data
}
```

Alternatively, if you choose to take the EOF approach, you would want to set a boolean upon the exception being caught, and use that boolean in your loop, but I do not recommend it:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));
boolean eof = false;
while (!eof) {
    try {
        // read and use data
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        eof = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is an old answer, I'd like to comment that `available()` does not tell you that you reached end-of-file. It merely tells you how many bytes you can read before being blocked (e.g. waiting for the next network packet). Thus the above recommended method is plain wrong.

Comment: @RealSkeptic While this isn't the right approach for reaching network packets, is there any case in which reading from a FIS will be blocked before reading EOF?

Comment: If your filesystem is network based, it definitely can. Or if you're reading from a fifo. Or from /dev/random. It's simply wrong to ignore the contract, and such bugs are hard to track down.

Answer (score 3):

`DataInputStream` has a lot of `readXXX()` methods that do throw `EOFException` but the method that you're using `DataInputStream.read()` ***does not*** throw `EOFException`.

To correctly identify the EOF while using `read()` implement your `while` loop as follows

```
int read = 0;
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while ((read = dis.read(b)) != -1) { // returns numOfBytesRead or -1 at EOF
  // parse, or write to output stream as
  dos.write(b, 0, read); // (byte[], offset, numOfBytesToWrite)
}
```

Comment: That works but then it's pointless to have wrapped the original stream with a DataInputStream!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FileInputStream`, here's an EOF method for a class that has a FileInputStream member called `fis`.

```
public boolean isEOF() 
{ 
    try { return fis.getChannel().position() >= fis.getChannel().size()-1; } 
    catch (IOException e) { return true; } 
}
```